# How do I get audio files of a specific file size?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-recording

Is there any way to use ffmpeg to accurately break audio files into smaller files of a specific file size, or pull a specific number of samples from a file?

I'm working with a speech-to-text API that needs audio chunks in *exactly* 160,000 bytes, or 80,000 16-bit samples.

I have a video stream, and I have an ffmpeg command to extract audio from it:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://MyFMSWorkspace/ingest/test/mp4:test_1000 live=1" -ar 16000 -f segment -segment_time 10 out%04d.wav
```

So now I have ~10 second audio chunks with a sample rate of 16 kHz. Is there any way to break this into exactly 160kb, 5 second files using ffmpeg?

I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -t 00:00:05.00 -i out0000.wav outCropped.wav
```

But the output was this:

```
Input #0, wav, from 'out0000.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, bitrate: 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 256 kb/s
Output #0, wav, to 'outCropped.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 pcm_s16le
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=     156kB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate= 256.1kbits/s
```

but now the size is 156kb

EDIT:

My finished command is:

```
ffmpeg -i "url" -map 0:1 -af aresample=16000,asetnsamples=16000 -f segment -segment_time 5 -segment_format sw out%04d.sw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That output looks perfectly right. That ffmpeg size is expressed in `KiB` although it says `kB`. 160000 bytes = `156.25 kB` + some header data. ffmpeg shows size with fractional part hidden. If you want a raw file, with no headers, output to `.raw` instead of `.wav`.

Comment: yeah, doing output to .sw (a raw type) got rid of the headers, and I was able to dial some other options to get exactly the number of samples I needed.

Answer (score 0):

For people converting video files to MP3s split into 30 minute segments:

```
ffmpeg -i "something.MP4" -q:a 0 -map a -f segment -segment_time 1800 FileNumber%04d.mp3
```

The `-q` option can only be used with libmp3lame and corresponds to the LAME `-V` option ([source](https://superuser.com/a/354662/924518))